# How can I google given sentence in python and get the most frequent words from that results?

Tags: python-3.x

For my homework, I need to write a python program which, google the given sentence and prints the most frequent 5 words related to that search.

How can do that ?

Is there a library or API ?

Thanks!!!

## EDIT

In that assigment I needed to solve NYTimes daily puzzle. To do that I need to do google search with the provided clues. I was looking for the some kind of API or library to do that.

I did it using selenium. Selenium is powerful to google search or related to some kind web page issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do a little more research and try this yourself first so that you can ask more specific questions about your approach and the code you are working on.

It is not exactly clear what text you would want to use to identify the top 5 most common words (i.e. the text in the Google search result pages, the actual text on the sites that are returned as part of the search, etc.) or how many results would be considered in your analysis.

With that said, I would recommend looking into the following:

For extracting text from the web, I would recommend you look into the library BeautifulSoup4.  You can install it by typing the following into your terminal:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

As for word frequency, you can you use nltk to analyze the text you return using beautiful soup and get the frequency or do other text based analysis.  You can install nltk by typing the following into your terminal:

```
pip install nltk
```

If you are against using nltk for doing your text analysis, you could do something like this with built in libraries to get counts of the most common words in some text:

```
# import your libraries
import re
from collections import Counter

# clean text from google retrieved with beautiful soup
text_from_google = 'This is some example text I use where I use the word 
example more than once for example'
text = text_from_google.lower().split()

# create a function to return the top n words in text
def get_top_words(text, num_words):

    # basic pre-processing to remove punctuation
    punc_filter = re.compile('.*[A-Za-z0-9].*')
    filtered_text = [word for word in text if punc_filter.match(word)]

    word_counts = Counter(filtered_text)

    return word_counts.most_common(num_words)

# get the top words
top_words = get_top_words(text, 5)

for word in top_words:
    print('The word {} was found {} times'.format(word[0], word[1]))
```